# IHttpHandler - A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have an IHttpHandler that receives XML from a third party, and I am able to resolve this issue by using context.Request.Unvalidated["FormDataItem"] to process the data.

However, when I attempt to redirect to another page using context.Response.Redirect("/IntegrationLoginPage.aspx", true); I get the following error

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
>   at - System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateHttpValueCollection(HttpValueCollection collection, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() at System.Web.UI.PageRequestManager.IsAsyncPostBackRequest(HttpRequestBase request) at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.HttpResponse_Redirecting(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)

How can I handle the validation issue allowing me to redirect, without turning off validation for the whole application in the web.config?

Comment: Have you tried the [Post, ValidateInput(false)] decorator?

Comment: Where would it go in the handler?

Comment: Note - This is not an MVC Application

Comment: Oh, sorry, can you out this in the markup of the IntegrationLoginPage.aspx:
<@ Page validateRequest="false" %>

Comment: I can but the error occurs prior to the redirect to IntegrationLoginPage.aspx on the handler.ashx.

Comment: It isn't very elegant, but I have the data I need using context.Request.Unvalidated["FormDataItem"] and I only need to redirect so I just ignore the error by catching it and doing nothing.                               catch (HttpRequestValidationException ex)
            {

            }